# How to return true if two Range objects have the same range in a for loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet where each row is an application. The last column CR writes if the applicant is eligible or not based on some criteria.

I am trying to loop through each application and check it for completeness.

For one condition:
If the loop is on the cell that says Yes/No for funding (AT), and value of the cell is Yes, and the cell next to it is empty, then return for the final column (CR) that application is incomplete.

I get complete when the applicant should be incomplete.

Is it because the cells are comparing the values and not the ranges?

```vb
For Each c In Range("B2:CI10").Cells
 
    completeness = "CR" & c.row
    Set completeness2 = Range(completeness)
 
    fundingCell = "AT" & c.row
    Set fundingCell2 = Range(fundingCell)
 
    If (c = fundingCell And fundingCell2.Value = "Yes" And IsEmpty(c.Offset(0, 1))) Then
        completeness2 = "incomplete"
    Else
        completeness2 = "Complete"
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```vb
Dim rw as range, rngComplete as range

For Each rw In Range("B2:CI10").entirerow.rows

    Set rngComplete = rw.columns("CR")
    
    if lcase(rw.columns("AT").value) = "yes" and len(rw.columns("AU").value) > 0 Then
        rngComplete =  "complete"
    else
        rngComplete =  "incomplete"
    end if

Next rw
```

Answer (score 0):

### Compare Objects

- The short answer is `If c Is Funding`. But this can be avoided.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CompletenessFunding()
    
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("AT2:AT10").Cells
        If c.Value = "Yes" And IsEmpty(c.Offset(0, 1)) Then
            Range("CR" & c.Row).Value = "Incomplete"
        Else
            Range("CR" & c.Row).Value = "Complete"
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

The inefficient version before understanding what the code was doing:

```
Sub CompletenessFundingInitial()
    
    Dim c As Range
    Dim Completeness As Range
    Dim Funding As Range
    
    For Each c In Range("B2:CI10").Cells
        Set Completeness = Range("CR" & c.Row)
        Set Funding = Range("AT" & c.Row)
        If c Is Funding And Funding.Value = "Yes" _
                And IsEmpty(c.Offset(0, 1)) Then
            Completeness.Value = "Incomplete"
        Else
            Completeness.Value = "Complete"
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```